# Excel creating lines of text automatically based on other cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of employee holidays. I'm wondering how to automatically generate a line of text for each of the employees, as below. Only employees with days off would generate a line of text. Greatful for any suggestions. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If your data is in `A3:B9`, then `=LET(x,FILTER(A3:B9,B3:B9>0),INDEX(x,,1)&" was on annual leave/sick for "&INDEX(x,,2) & " days during the selected period")`

Comment: Since it's numbers you could even skip using `>0`: `FILTER(A3:B9,B3:B9)`